# Why are my Ponderosa lemon tree leaves yellowing from the veins outward?

Tags: diagnosis, fruit-trees, leaves

My Ponderosa lemon tree is 3-4 years old, but I've only had it for 6-7 months. It has flowered and is now producing 4 lemons but two leaves fell off with this yellowing from the veins in the center outward toward the circular edges.

It is in a 5-6 gallon wooden barrel container, has been fertilized twice since the beginning of March with Jobes fruit & tree, Citrus tone organic, Dr. Earths all purpose. Can you tell me what is going on?  It has also started to lean a little bit but I'm thinking that's just the way it's growing?

About watering, I water both my pomegranate and lemon tree once a week. The temperature here in New York has been very bi-polar! It has gone from 45 degrees to 80 within days. We've had a lot of rain storms, and water levels are way above average at record levels since 1829.

Comment: can you please post a picture?

Comment: pH of your soil is important.  In combination with fluctuating temperatures, that could cause chemicals/nutrients to be unavailable to the tree.  Could you please post exactly how much fertilizer and the formulations for these fertilizers.  What is the drainage like?  Is it just soil or is there a layer of rock or gravel below the soil and above the drainage holes?  Are there drainage holes?  Is your barrel raised above the surface of your deck/patio by a quarter inch?  Don't worry about leaning.  You have to send a picture of the tree and the pot.  Please. Were the leaves older or younger?

Comment: Why are you watering it when it's raining?